# Se usato come insulto, "merda" può essere maschile (cioè, "un merda")?

Tags: word-usage, gender

Si può dire, ad esempio,

> Tuo cugino è un merda,

con l'articolo maschile "un", nello stesso modo che si direbbe "Tuo cugino è uno stronzo"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: È molto insolito, ma è importante perché “il Merda” era uno dei numerosi epiteti con cui Gadda parlava di Mussolini, tra cui Giuda, Mascelluto, Maccherone, Maramaldo, Maledito Merdonio, Minchione ottimo massimo, Somaro Principe, Nullapensante, Gaglioffo, Sozzo, Scacarcione, Smargiasso Impestato, Gallinaccio, Quer Tale, Fetente, Fava, Farabutto, Testa di Morto, il Gran Cacchio e appunto il Merda (vedi [qui](https://www.corriere.it/opinioni/18_ottobre_08/c-era-volta-galateo-linguistico-d3f91b7a-cb0f-11e8-9a02-946640b28e26.shtml), o facendo una ricerca con "il merda" e "gadda").

Comment: Si chiede se “un merda” sia una locuzione accettabile in italiano. Sicuramente l’OP ha dei dubbi in merito. Se si chiarisce il senso della domanda la risposta può essere chiara, mirata e utile.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111770/discussion-on-question-by-f-k-juliano-se-usato-come-insulto-merda-puo-essere).

Comment: Il tempo passa... Nessuno è in grado di scrivere una risposta? Sono sicura che non è così. Spero veder presto una buona risposta per poter così concedere il "bounty".

Answer (score 1):

Sì e no.

Merda è femminile. In particolare, merda deriva dal latino, dove è sempre al femminile.

Quindi è giusto dire "UNA merda" ma non "UN merda".

Tuttavia, può essere usato come appellativo al maschile : "Lo chiamano il Merda" (vedi anche il commento di DaG su Mussolini).

Questo perché l'appellativo (che definisce un soprannome con cui si chiama una persona) segue il genere della persona di cui si sta parlando.

Un esempio simile è dato dalla parola "bomba". Bomba in italiano è femminile, eppure diversi personaggi (reali o immaginari) sono stati chiamati "il Bomba".

Comment: Tutto giusto, ma sono considerazioni generali che toccano solo in parte il cuore della domanda. In particolare, siamo sicuri che “l'appellativo ... segue il genere della persona di cui si sta parlando”? A un uomo che si dà via facilmente diresti “sei un puttana”? Personalmente ritengo che all'atto pratico si eviti la differenza tra i generi, usando un termine diverso o un giro di parole (non a caso, in genere si dice “sei un pezzo di merda” o simili).

Comment: @DaG: Infatti, in spagnolo si dice anche "es un puta" (e in catalano "és un puta"), anche se "puta" è un sostantivo femminile. Eccone un esempio: https://books.google.es/books?id=vOtPDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22es+un+puta%22&source=bl&ots=ELLqStac9U&sig=ACfU3U0QgmbugqsIitikPy6E8d2fuH3-iQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFlaWwsanrAhV5AmMBHflIAz0Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22es%20un%20puta%22&f=false. Ma sono contenta perché perlomeno per questa domanda il bounty sta attirando attività positiva.

Comment: @DaG:  Immagino che A. Darwin usi "appellativo" come sinonimo di soprannome. "Un putana" o "una putana", con l'articolo indeterminativo, non mi sembra siano i soprannomi di nessuno.

Comment: Per favore, @DaG, potresti chiarire cosa vuoi dire con «siamo sicuri che “l'appellativo ... segue il genere della persona di cui si sta parlando”?». Se per "appellativo" s'intende "soprannome", non riesco a capire il senso di questa tua frase.

Comment: @Charo: Bisognerebbe capire che cosa intenda A. Darwin. A parte pochi casi come quelli menzionati qui, che non costituiscono una regola, normalmente non si altera il genere grammaticale di un sostantivo quando lo si usa come appellativo.

Comment: Ma cosa vuoi dire con "appellativo", @DaG? Secondo il Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appellativo), l'accezione più comune se usato come sostantivo è "soprannome o epiteto dato a persona".

Comment: @DaG: "normalmente non si altera il genere grammaticale di un sostantivo quando lo si usa come appellativo" significa che si usa dare un soprannome femminile a un uomo o maschile a una donna senza alterarne il genere grammaticale?

Comment: @DaG: Ho l'impressione che per "appellativo"  A. Darwin intenda "soprannome" mentre tu intenda una cosa diversa. È così?

Comment: @Charo: Per “appellativo” intendo “soprannome, epiteto”, come i dizionari e come, spero, A. Darwin. Che cos'altro hai in mente? E, come già dicevo, non suona proprio dire di un uomo “un/il puttana” o di una donna, che so, “una/la macigno”, a parte pochi casi per così dire tradizionali.

Comment: @DaG: Io interpreto la frase di A. Darwin come "quando si dà un soprannome a una persona, se è un uomo si fa con l'articolo maschile (esempi di *Ragazzi di vita di Pasolini*: "il Caciotta", "il Lenzetta", "il Piattoletta"), se è una donna si fa con l'articolo femminile". Non è così? Poi, gli esempi che hai fatto nel tuo commento precedente ("puttana", "macigno"), non mi sembrano soprannomi, ma forse sono io che non capisco cosa vuol dire "soprannome". In ogni caso, "non si usa dire di un uomo *un/il puttana* o di una donna *una/la macigno*" non mi sembra in contradizione con la frase di A.Darw

Comment: @DaG:  Forse stai suggerendo che si dovrebbe aggiungere alla risposta qualcosa come "Non è molto frequente usare sostantivi femminili come soprannomi di uomini o nomi maschili come soprannomi di donne, ma a volte si fa, come si vede in questi esempi"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112057/discussion-between-charo-and-dag).

Comment: Non so se stai ricevendo le notifiche del chat, @A.Darwin, per questa ragione scrivo qui. Potresti cercare di migliorare un po' la risposta tenendo conto di quello che si è discusso? In particolare, abbiamo parlato di una frase che non si capisce del tutto bene.

Comment: E aggiungo che questa risposta non risponde alla domanda, che non riguarda gli appellativi (un simile equivoco c'era già stato nei primi commenti ora spostati in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111770/discussion-on-question-by-f-k-juliano-se-usato-come-insulto-merda-puo-essere).