# Significato di "zoza"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Massimo, stai diventando una schiappa, una **zoza**, una molla scassata. Scendevi a sedici metri te ne sei scordato? e non ti faceva mai male niente. Quella volta a Nìsida, sott’acqua ti dovevo lasciare!»

Si tratta di un romanzo ambientato a Napoli.

Non ho trovato il termine "zoza" su nessun dizionario. Da una ricerca su Google mi è sembrato capire che possa trattarsi di un napoletanismo. È chiaro che nel contesto del brano è usato come un epiteto, ma potreste spiegare cosa vuol dire?

Comment: Notare che non dice “un schiappa”, “un molla”... ;)

Comment: Sì, @DaG: l'avevo notato e mi è sembrato interessante per quanto riguarda [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13173/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sull'origine di questo vocabolo si racconta che alla fine del '700 le salse preparate dai cuochi francesi a Napoli non furono apprezzate dal popolo, che le considerava una schifezza. Il termine sauces,  storpiato in sos e poi in zoza, divenne sinonimo di cosa (ed anche persona) ripugnante, disgustosa. Il termine dialettale oggi ha ampia diffusione, fino a diventare un epiteto offensivo: "si' 'na zoza! ", che vuol dire "sei una schifezza".

Qui un link ad un sito che tratta dell'origine etimologica del termine (che però non cita nessuna fonte autorevole): https://www.vesuviolive.it/cultura-napoletana/proverbi-napoletani/152518-deriva-termine-napoletano-zoza/.

Questa storia sull'origine del termine viene anche raccontata nel libro [*I colori del gusto*](https://books.google.es/books?id=e0RIAQAAIAAJ&q=zoza+napoletano+schifezza&dq=zoza+napoletano+schifezza&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqjp_Tka_rAhUKBGMBHS8ZB-IQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ), dell'Accademia italiana della cucina:

> Fu soprattutto con il lungo regno di Ferdinando IV, poi I, che la corte napoletana primeggiò in Europa per lusso, eleganza e  e magnificenza, sempre in competizione con quella di Parigi per una eterna gara tra la regina Maria Carolina e la e la sfortunata sorella Maria Antonietta, regina di Francia. La moda e la cucina francese entrarono di prepotenza nelle abitudini dei Napoletani  portando una ventata di novità sia nell'abbigliamento che nell'alimentazione, nei pranzi ufficiali e nelle occasioni più importanti l'etichetta imponeva solo cucina francese accompagnata  accompagnata sempre e solo da vini francesi. Per adeguarsi ed essere all'altezza, molte casate nobili ingaggiavano cuochi francesi, che in segno di rispetto erano chiamati *monzù*, inoltre molti termini gastronomici furono mutuati dal francese entrando di diritto nel linguaggio quotidiano, molto spesso storpiati nella pronuncia o nella grafica: *gatto*, *ragù*, *sartù*, *bignè*, e così via. 
>  
>       La ricca cucina nobiliare ebbe a Napoli i suoi codificatori che raccolsero le ricette descrivendole in importanti ricettari: il Cuoco galante (1773) e il Credenziere di buon gusto (1778) di Vincenzo Corrado, la Cucina Casereccia di M. F. (1807, anonimo), e la Cucina teorico-pratica (1837) pubblicata pubblicata in ben nove edizioni dal nobile cavalier Ippolito Cavalcanti duca di Buonvicino, testo quest'ultimo considerato un caposaldo della gastronomia napoletana per aver dato voce anche alla cucina della borghesia, con la descrizione di molte pietanze ancora in uso nell'attuale cucina quotidiana​. Pochi però sono i manicaretti della cucina aristocratica sopravvissuti e giunti fino a noi: con l'Unità d'Italia la dinastia Borbonica fu esiliata, la corte e la nobiltà furono fagocitate di nuovi personaggi e, disperse dai nuovi eventi, rivosero la loro attenzione ad altri interessi. Da parte sua il popolo, sia in città che nelle campagne, non aveva mai adottato gli intingoli pasticciati e le complesse preparazioni francesi, verso le quali provava tale ripugnanza che il termine francese *sauce* - salsa, storpiato in *zoza*, divenne sinonimo di abominevole schifezza.

Come fonte per dare conferma a quanto spiegato sul significato, possiamo citare questo passo del libro [*Origini*](https://books.google.es/books?id=SKBfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=zoza+napoletano+schifezza&source=bl&ots=XqRC3mpOgU&sig=ACfU3U1QblkoUpAG7WZ3Dg2YvJK9D3uZCg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL_57fi6_rAhWxDmMBHdDoDP04ChDoATAJegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=zoza%20napoletano%20schifezza&f=false) di Giovanni Bausilio, autore di altri libri sulla lingua napoletana:

> Ogni napoletano è un alchimista del caffè: tutti hanno teorie, [...]  alcuni hanno addirittura rinunciato a prepararlo da soli perché la loro arte non era abbastanza raffinata affinché il risultato non fosse *na zoza o ciufeca* che tradotte sta per schifezza.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112090/discussion-on-answer-by-luciano-petrillo-significato-di-zoza).

Comment: Aggiungo che ho osservato che qualche utente ha "downvotato" questa risposta: so che a volte questo non è una bella esperienza, ma non dovresti mai prenderlo come qualcosa di personale. Dalla discussione generata nei commenti, mi è sembrato intuire che la ragione del voto negativo è che alcuni utenti aspettano risposte corredate da fonti. (Adesso però si è aggiunta qualche fonte.)

Comment: Ci sono utenti che postano nei commenti quello che tu avevi scritto all'inizio come risposta, ma, secondo la documentazione ufficiale, i commenti non si dovrebbero usare in questo modo. Vedi, ad esempio: https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/should-we-be-using-comments-as-substitutes-for-answers. Beh... spero veder molte altre tue risposte su questo sito.